# ASP.NET Core 6 - Policy based authentication scheme not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

In my app, I'm authenticating and authorizing every request by `Windows Authentication` using the following code:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("DevOps-Admin")
        .Build();

    options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.IsDevOpsAdmin, policy);
    options.FallbackPolicy = policy;
});
```

Now I have to additionally support `Basic Authentication`, but just for a specific API controller. So I tried to set the authentication scheme by the policy ([as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0#selecting-the-scheme-with-policies)). But when I change my code to the following, it doesn't work anymore, it returns 403 - forbidden:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("DevOps-Admin")
        .Build();

    options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.IsDevOpsAdmin, policy);
    options.FallbackPolicy = policy;
});
```

The output says:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
      DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
      RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (DevOps-Admin)
```

I expected both code snippets to do exactly the same?

My thought process was, that if I can change my code so that the policy selects the authentication scheme, I could just add another policy with a scheme "basic" which then does basic authentication and authorization. Then I could add the attribute `Authorize` to my controller and set the policy to the new one.

Did a lot of googling and watched a Pluralsight course about Authentication and Authorization, but I still seem to don't get it :(

### UPDATE 1:

If I comment out the line `.RequireRole("DevOps-Admin")` in the second code snippet, it works. It's weird, because when I look at the claims, every AD group is there including `DevOps-Admin`, so why does `RequireRole` return `false` in this case?

Comment: so the issue has solved?

Comment: Nope, because I need the line `.RequireRole("DevOps-Admin")` to make sure, the user has that specific role. I was just trying to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue has not been solved yet, when i faced a related issue the solution was setting the RoleClaimType from TokenValidationParameters so the IsInRole recognized the customRole.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).